# WCF Service using https

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, https

I try to get a WCF Service running using https. The following code works for http

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;


namespace WebServiceTest
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(service), new Uri("http://localhost:8083")))
            {
                var secureWebHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding() { Name = "secureHttpWeb" };
                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Instance), secureWebHttpBinding, "");
                serviceHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service running...");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Stop the host
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    interface Instance
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getstatus/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string getStatus();
    }

    class service : Instance
    {
        public string getStatus()
        {

            return "test";
        }
    }


}
```

So what I tried to get this running for https is change the uri to use https and add the `WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport` to the constructor of `WebHttpBinding`

Instead of

```
using (var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(service), new Uri("http://localhost:8083")))
```

it would be

```
using (var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(service), new Uri("https://localhost:8083")))
```

and instead of

```
var secureWebHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding() { Name = "secureHttpWeb" };
```

it would be

```
var secureWebHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { Name = "secureHttpWeb" };
```

**I don't get an exception, but the endpoint is not reachable. What am I missing?**

Comment: Have you bound an SSL certificate to your host? HTTPS needs a certificate.

Comment: No I didn't do that. Can I do this via code? (I'd like to not change the config, because I don't actually get how the code corresponds to the config). Can I use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: [Selfhosting a WCF service over Https](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/james_osbornes_blog/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https/) shows how to do this with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Yeah, you can use self-signed SSL certificate. This article can be helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/james_osbornes_blog/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https/

Comment: Thank you guys. The link you provided actually were the steps for me to create my test application. So if you add this as an answer instead of comment I can mark it as the proper answer :)